# Validate dynamic fields in laravel form

Tags: laravel

I can't validate this form with Laravel 5.2, this is my code:

My view:

```
@for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++)
    {!! Form::control('text', 0, "items[$i]", $errors, trans('back/blog.content')) !!}
@endfor
```

---

My validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'summary' => 'required|max:65000',
        'content' => 'required|max:65000',
    ];
    foreach($this->request->get('items') as $key => $val) {
        $rules['items['.$key.']'] = 'required|max:10';
    }
    return  $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using laravel 5.2 you can validate an array

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'items.*' => 'required'
]);
```

for details https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases

If you are using lower than 5.2 version you can do like this

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

$v->each('items', ['required']);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but im not using Validator::make(), Im using the extension of rules() function... I have tested in it your suggestions but dont work

Comment: that's not a big deal to use validation or anything i gave you and example of array you can use 'items.*' => 'required' in any array $rules or anything.